# App doesn't working after deploying on production server. Development is fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, routes

My app works on my local machine, but won't work on the production server.

Using capistrano, everything is up and running under /var/www/current.

Restarted web server.

Getting the site's custom 404, but can't even retrieve stuff out of /public/images using the direct link.

Getting this in the log:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template access/index with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rxml, :builder, :erb, :rjs, :rhtml], :formats=>[:html]} in view paths "/var/www/releases/20110703002055/app/views", "/var/www/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views"):
```

I've been playing with routes.rb - here is the only line from it right now:

```
root :to => 'access#index', :as => 'access'
```

I do have these in access_controller.rb:

```
  def index    
  end

  def welcome
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # welcome.html.erb
    end
  end
```

I have a template index.html.erb and welcome.html.erb in the app/views/access directory.

Comment: Silly question: did you add those files to your source control and push to the server?

Comment: I thought I did but that was exactly what was wrong. I'll be doing it from the command line instead of Textmate from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know capistrano, but if you are using Git or something like that to push your code to your server, it looks like you have not added all the files to your repository. (it whines over not finding access/index.html.erb)

In git it's like:

```
git add .
git commit -m "adding missing files"
```

Comment: All the files are on the production server, including the templates... I handchecked everything. Something else that I'm noticing is that when I go to my users/new option, I am getting an error stating my recaptcha public keys can't be found. (ActionView::Template::Error (No public key specified.):) For some reason the initializers/recaptcha.rb is not working on my production server. Not having an issue on my development server.

Comment: Another example: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/td_thumb.png"):

Comment: Ugh, that was it! Not sure why committing from Textmate wasn't getting all of my changes.

I did what you said: added the files, committed. I then pushed the branched, redeployed and everything came up.

Thanks!